# Tkinter - Preload window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, lag

I started building a python tkinter gui, the problem is, after adding many features to the gui, the loading started looking **really ugly**. When starting the mainloop, a blank window shows up for a few miniseconds before the widgets are loaded, the same happens with the other Toplevel windows ( except the ones with few static elements that don't need updates ).

### My question is

Is there a way to 'preload' the window so that when I would call it, it would start smoothly?

#### For example

```
root = MyTkRoot()
root.build_stuff_before_calling()
root.mainloop() # Smooth without widget loading lag
```

#### Part of my code

```
from root_gui import Root
import threading
from time import sleep
from data_handler import DataHandler


def handle_conn():
    DataHandler.try_connect()
    smtp_client.refresh()


def conn_manager(): # Working pretty well
    while 'smtp_client' in locals():
        sleep(3)
        handle_conn()


smtp_client = Root()
handle_conn()


MyConnManager = threading.Thread(target=conn_manager)
MyConnManager.start() # Thanks to the second thread, the tk window doesn't have to wait for 3 seconds before loading the widgets.
smtp_client.mainloop()
```

#### The full project on git

Too much code to put in here...

https://github.com/cernyd/smtp_client

Comment: Your program must be HUGE. This is where Python loses the battle LOL! I am also looking forward for suggestions.

Comment: added a git link, it must be my fault most likely, Idk how to improve the performace :S

Comment: You might need to integrate some C/C++ into your Python code.

Comment: But is it absolutely certain that this is caused by the nature of the python language itself? Is this the performace boundary?

Comment: Perhaps. Honestly, I am even kinda scared to check out your code lol

Comment: I started with tkinter about a week ago, you can't expect any rocket science haha

Comment: I will take a look

Comment: I think this is purely based on the specific implementations, on my mac it takes about 0.8 seconds to open the window and all the widgets are already there when it opens.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit Anniversary edition

Comment: ok, using my brothers Windows computer I see what you mean, I tried @double_j's solution but using `self.after(0,self.attributes, "-alpha",1.0)` in the root_gui's initialize method and it worked as you want.

Comment: Where do I put this? Inside of the __init__ of the root?

Comment: yes, directly below `tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` I added `self.attributes("-alpha",0.0) ; self.after(0,self.attributes,"-alpha",1.0)`

Comment: This solution worked really well! If you post it as an answer, I would upvote!

Comment: do you have calls to `update` or `update_idletasks` in your code? You can't see a window until you process events, which is what mainloop does. However, if you call `update` or `update_idletasks`, any parts of the window that have already been created will appear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On your operating system tkinter seems to show the base `Tk` window before loading it's widgets causing that few milliseconds of blank window.  To make it appear with all the widgets already loaded you will need to hide the window when starting and `.after` it has loaded show it again.

There are a number of ways to show and hide a window, personally I'd use `.withdraw()` to remove the window from the window manager (like it was never there) then `.deiconify()` (basically "unminimize") to show the window again.

```
class TEST(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kw):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kw)
        self.withdraw() #hide the window
        self.after(0,self.deiconify) #as soon as possible (after app starts) show again
        #setup app...
```

An alternative to withdrawing the window completely is to start it minimized with `.iconify()` so it will appear on the taskbar/dock but won't open the window until it is completely loaded.

Another way to hide/show the window is by changing the `-alpha` property as [@double_j has done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39211981/5827215) but I would not recommend that in production code because the window is technically still there, it (and the close button etc.) can be clicked on /interacted with for a brief moment before showing which could be undesired, as well it's behaviour can be ambiguous amongst operating systems, from http://wiki.tcl.tk/9457:

> ### Macintosh Attributes
>
> -alpha double controls opacity (from 0.0 to 1.0)
>   
> ...
>
> ### Unix/X11 Attributes
>
> -alpha double controls opacity (from 0.0 to 1.0).
>  This requires a compositing window manager to have any effect. [compiz] is one such,
>   and xfwm4 (for the XFCE desktop) is another.
>   
> ...
>
> ### Windows Attributes
>
> -alpha double how opaque the overall window is; **note that changing between 1.0 and any other value may cause the window to flash** (Tk
>   changes the class of window used to implement the toplevel).

So on some unix machines `-alpha` may have no effect and on windows it may cause the window to flash (probably not an issue before it is even opened but still worth noting)

Where as `withdraw` and `deiconify` works identically amongst all platforms as far as I am aware.

Comment: Thanks man! I really appreciate it, this made my window properly load up and not flash white for a second first.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes. You can set the window to appear as though you can't see it. Perform any code that takes time, and then display the window.

Here's how:

```
class MyTkRoot(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)  # make window transparent
        # build gui...
        self.after(0, self.attributes, "-alpha", 1.0)  # back to normal
root = MyTkRoot()
root.mainloop()
```

[Here's](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.attributes-method) a reference to the code with the example of a Toplevel. It will also work with the root however.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What exactly does this piece of code do? How do I toggle that on/off?

Comment: Sure, I added a link

Comment: @double_j How can the OP use making his window tranparent to solve his problem? Is this really relevant to the question? Am I missing something?

Comment: @ParvizKarimli Part of the question was "a blank window shows up for a few miniseconds". This would handle that. Also the the main question was "Is there a way to 'preload' the window so that when I would call it, it would start smoothly?". Once again, this would handle that.

Comment: I need to make the window visible again AFTER calling mainloop because otherwise it wont help.

Comment: @double_j Making the window transparent won't get the program run faster. Only difference is that the user won't see any overloaded window, but will still need to wait for a while to use the program.

Comment: @ParvizKarimli This does handle the aspect of the "loading started looking really ugly". I don't think the OP is asking to have faster code.

Comment: this works but only if `root.attributes('-alpha', 1.0)` is called directly after the mainloop starts, I.E. using `root.after(0,root.attributes, "-alpha",1.0)`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen This is true, thanks. I was taking it from the OP's example. I've made the appropriate edits.

Comment: Ok guys, problem solved thanks to @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, thanks for your time!

Comment: That is not the appropriate edits, you need to set it back to opaque **after** the mainloop starts, doing it before hand by calling it directly doesn't work, you need to specify calling it afterwards with the `root.after` method. setting a delay of `0` milliseconds will mean it gets called immediately after the window starts and widgets are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your the project in your repository, I revised the code and dumped it all into one file. The following is the results from refactoring your modules and files into a fully self-contained program. The one thing that it is missing is the `Resource` class that handles all of the external dependencies.

You can see the [complete program](http://pastebin.com/bRZuq72L) on PasteBin.com.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import base64
import contextlib
import email.mime.text
import enum
import functools
import pathlib
import pickle
import pickletools
import re
import smtplib
import socket
import sys
import threading
import tkinter.messagebox
import traceback
import zlib


# Dump all of tkinter's constants into the local namespace.
from tkinter.constants import *


# Import custom modules in a way that an IDE will recognize them.
with Resource.load('affinity.py'), \
     Resource.load('threadbox.py'), \
     Resource.load('safetkinter.py'):
    try:
        from .safetkinter import *
    except SystemError:
        from safetkinter import *
    try:
        from . import threadbox
    except SystemError:
        import threadbox


# Patch the messagebox module to use a thread-safe version of Message.
tkinter.messagebox.Message = Message


# Create an enumeration to represents various program states.
Status = enum.Enum('Status', 'mail_label login_button connection_error')


def event_handler(method):
    """Allow command/event handlers to be marked and written more easily."""
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, event=None):
        nonlocal none_counter
        none_counter += event is None
        method(self)
        # print('Commands handled:', none_counter)
    none_counter = 0
    return wrapper


class SMTPClient(Frame):

    """Widget for sending emails through a GUI program in Python."""

    TITLE = 'SMTP Mail Sender'

    AT_ICON = 'at.ico'
    HELP_ICON = 'help.ico'
    HELP_TEXT = 'get_help.txt'

    IS_TARGET = r'\A(\w|\.)+@\w+\.\w+\Z'
    IS_SUBJECT = r'\S+'
    IS_MESSAGE = r'\S+'

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        """Create an application containing a single SMTPClient widget."""
        root = cls.create_application_root()
        cls.create_windows_bindings(root)
        cls.attach_window_icon(root)
        cls.setup_class_instance(root)
        root.mainloop()

    @classmethod
    def create_application_root(cls):
        """Create and configure the main application window."""
        root = Tk()
        root.title(cls.TITLE)
        # root.resizable(False, False)
        root.minsize(275, 200)
        root.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)
        return root

    @classmethod
    def create_windows_bindings(cls, root):
        """Change some global bindings to work like Microsoft products."""
        root.bind_all('<Control-Key-a>', cls.handle_control_a)
        root.bind_all('<Control-Key-A>', cls.handle_control_a)
        root.bind_class('Text', '<Control-Key-/>', lambda event: 'break')

    @staticmethod
    def handle_control_a(event):
        """Treat Control-A as would be expected on a Windows system."""
        widget = event.widget
        if isinstance(widget, Entry):
            widget.selection_range(0, END)
            return 'break'
        if isinstance(widget, Text):
            widget.tag_add(SEL, 1.0, END + '-1c')
            return 'break'

    @classmethod
    def attach_window_icon(cls, root):
        """Generate and use the icon in the window's corner."""
        with Resource.load(cls.AT_ICON) as handle:
            root.iconbitmap(handle)

    @classmethod
    def setup_class_instance(cls, root):
        """Build a SMTPClient instance that expects to be have size changes."""
        widget = cls(root)
        widget.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        """Initialize the SMTPClient instance and configure for operation."""
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.__tk = self.capture_root()
        self.create_bindings()
        self.__to_entry = self.__subject_entry = self.__message_text = \
            self.__quit_button = self.__send_button = self.__from_label = \
            self.__to_label = self.__subject_label = self.__login_button = \
            self.__grip = None
        self.create_widgets()
        self.configure_grid()
        self.__data_handler = DataHandler()
        self.__connector = self.after_idle(self.try_connect)

    def destroy(self):
        """Cancel the connection system before closing."""
        self.after_cancel(self.__connector)
        super().destroy()

    def capture_root(self):
        """Capture the rook (Tk instance) of this application."""
        widget = self.master
        while not isinstance(widget, Tk):
            widget = widget.master
        return widget

    def create_bindings(self):
        """Bind the frame to any events that it will need to handle."""
        self.__tk.bind('<Control-Key-h>', self.handle_help)
        self.__tk.bind('<Control-Key-H>', self.handle_help)
        self.__tk.bind('<Control-Key-l>', self.handle_login)
        self.__tk.bind('<Control-Key-L>', self.handle_login)
        self.__tk.bind('<Key>', self.handle_update)
        self.__tk.bind('<Return>', self.handle_send)

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create all the widgets that will be placed in this frame."""
        self.__to_entry = Entry(self)
        self.__subject_entry = Entry(self)
        self.__message_text = Text(self)
        self.__quit_button = Button(
            self,
            text='Quit',
            command=self.__tk.destroy
        )
        self.__send_button = Button(
            self,
            text='Send',
            command=self.do_send,
            state=DISABLED
        )
        self.__from_label = Label(self, text='From:')
        self.__to_label = Label(self, text='To:')
        self.__subject_label = Label(self, text='Subject:')
        self.__login_button = Button(
            self,
            text='Login Before Sending',
            command=self.do_login
        )
        self.__grip = Sizegrip(self)

    def configure_grid(self):
        """Place all widgets on the grid in their respective locations."""
        pad = dict(padx=5, pady=5)
        self.__from_label.grid(row=0, column=0, **pad)
        self.__login_button.grid(
            row=0,
            column=1,
            columnspan=4,
            sticky=EW,
            **pad
        )
        self.__to_label.grid(row=1, column=0, **pad)
        self.__to_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=EW, **pad)
        self.__subject_label.grid(row=2, column=0, **pad)
        self.__subject_entry.grid(
            row=2,
            column=1,
            columnspan=4,
            sticky=EW,
            **pad
        )
        self.__message_text.grid(
            row=3,
            column=0,
            columnspan=5,
            sticky=NSEW,
            **pad
        )
        self.__quit_button.grid(row=4, column=2, **pad)
        self.__send_button.grid(row=4, column=3, **pad)
        self.__grip.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky=SE, **pad)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    @event_handler
    def handle_help(self):
        """Open the help window and show a message for the user."""
        with Resource.load(self.HELP_TEXT) as text, \
                Resource.load(self.HELP_ICON) as icon:
            TextViewer.load(self.__tk, text, icon)

    @event_handler
    def handle_login(self):
        """Decide if the user should be able to login to the server."""
        if self.current_status == Status.login_button:
            self.do_login()

    @event_handler
    def handle_update(self):
        """Decide if it should be possible to send an e-mail or not."""
        to = self.__to_entry.get()
        subject = self.__subject_entry.get()
        message = self.__message_text.get(0.0, END)
        self.__send_button['state'] = ACTIVE if self.is_target(to) \
            and self.is_subject(subject) \
            and self.is_message(message) \
            and self.__data_handler.is_connected else DISABLED

    @classmethod
    def is_target(cls, text):
        """Determine if this is an acceptable e-mail address."""
        return bool(re.search(cls.IS_TARGET, text))

    @classmethod
    def is_subject(cls, text):
        """Determine if this is an acceptable subject line."""
        return bool(re.search(cls.IS_SUBJECT, text))

    @classmethod
    def is_message(cls, text):
        """Determine if this is an acceptable message to send."""
        return bool(re.search(cls.IS_MESSAGE, text))

    @event_handler
    def handle_send(self):
        """Send only if the application is ready to do so."""
        if self.__send_button['state'] == ACTIVE:
            self.do_send()

    def do_send(self):
        """Start a thread to send an e-mail in an asynchronous method."""
        threading.Thread(target=self.send_thread).start()

    @threadbox.MetaBox.thread
    def send_thread(self):
        """Try to send an e-mail and display the results of the attempt."""
        destination = self.__to_entry.get()
        try:
            self.__data_handler.send(
                destination,
                self.__subject_entry.get(),
                self.__message_text.get(0.0, END)
            )
        except:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror(
                'Error',
                'An exception has occurred.\n'
                'Continue for more details.',
                master=self
            )
            TextViewer(self.__tk, 'Traceback', traceback.format_exc())
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(
                'Success',
                'The message was sent successfully to {}.'.format(destination),
                master=self
            )

    @property
    def current_status(self):
        """Find out what status the program currently is in."""
        return (Status.connection_error
                if not self.__data_handler.is_connected else
                Status.login_button
                if not self.__data_handler.is_logged_in else
                Status.mail_label)

    def do_login(self):
        """Open the login window and also the user to supply credentials."""
        with Resource.load('login.ico') as icon:
            LoginWindow(self.__tk, icon, self.__data_handler)
        self.__login_button['text'] = self.__data_handler.username or ''
        self.refresh()

    def try_connect(self):
        """Repeatedly try to connect to the server every 0.6 seconds."""
        if not self.__data_handler.is_connected:
            self.__data_handler.try_connect(self.refresh)
        self.__connector = self.after(600, self.try_connect)

    def refresh(self, is_connected=False):
        """Let the user know if there is a connection to the server."""
        if is_connected:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(
                'Server',
                'Your connection is live!',
                master=self
            )


class TextViewer(Toplevel):

    """Widget designed to show text in a window."""

    BACKGROUND = '#FFFFFF'
    FOREGROUND = '#000000'
    WIDTH = 800
    HEIGHT = 600
    X_OFFSET = 10
    Y_OFFSET = 10

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, parent, text_handle, icon_handle):
        """Open a TextViewer with information loaded from a file."""
        with text_handle.open('rt') as file:
            title, *text = map(str.strip, file)
        cls(parent, title, '\n'.join(text), icon_handle)

    def __init__(self, parent, title, text, icon_handle=None):
        """Initializes the window for the reader to see its contents."""
        super().__init__(parent, borderwidth=5)
        if icon_handle is not None:
            self.iconbitmap(icon_handle)
        self.geometry('={}x{}+{}+{}'.format(
            self.WIDTH,
            self.HEIGHT,
            parent.winfo_rootx() + self.X_OFFSET,
            parent.winfo_rooty() + self.Y_OFFSET
        ))
        self.__frame_text = self.__frame_buttons = self.__okay_button = \
            self.__scrollbar_view = self.__text_view = None
        self.create_widgets()
        self.configure_widgets()
        self.title(title)
        self.transient(parent)
        self.grab_set()
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.okay)
        self.__text_view.focus_set()
        self.create_bindings()
        self.__text_view.insert(0.0, text)
        self.__text_view['state'] = DISABLED
        self.wait_window()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Populates the window with the widgets that will be needed."""
        self.__frame_text = Frame(self, relief=SUNKEN, height=700)
        self.__frame_buttons = Frame(self)
        self.__okay_button = Button(
            self.__frame_buttons,
            text='Close',
            command=self.okay,
            takefocus=FALSE
        )
        self.__scrollbar_view = Scrollbar(
            self.__frame_text,
            orient=VERTICAL,
            takefocus=FALSE
        )
        self.__text_view = Text(
            self.__frame_text,
            wrap=WORD,
            fg=self.FOREGROUND,
            bg=self.BACKGROUND,
            highlightthickness=0
        )

    def configure_widgets(self):
        """Put them in their proper places throughout the layout."""
        self.__scrollbar_view['command'] = self.__text_view.yview
        self.__text_view['yscrollcommand'] = self.__scrollbar_view.set
        self.__okay_button.pack()
        self.__scrollbar_view.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.__text_view.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
        self.__frame_buttons.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        self.__frame_text.pack(side=TOP, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

    @event_handler
    def okay(self):
        """Close the window."""
        self.destroy()

    def create_bindings(self):
        """Allow the window to respond to certain events."""
        self.bind('<Return>', self.okay)
        self.bind('<Escape>', self.okay)


class DataHandler:

    """Handler for communications with a SMTP server."""

    HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    PORT = 587

    __slots__ = (
        '__is_logged_in',
        '__is_connected',
        '__server',
        '__username',
        '__password'
    )

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes the DataHandler instance's various flags."""
        self.__is_logged_in = False
        self.__is_connected = self.__server = self.__username = \
            self.__password = None
        self.__cancel_connection()

    @property
    def is_logged_in(self):
        """Checks whether or not the instance believes it is logged in."""
        return self.__is_logged_in

    @property
    def is_connected(self):
        """Checks whether or not the instance believes it is connected."""
        return self.__is_connected

    @staticmethod
    def __check_string(value, name):
        """Verify that the string has a value type and value."""
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError('{} must be of type str'.format(name))
        if not value:
            raise ValueError('{} must not be an empty string'.format(name))

    def __get_username(self):
        """Retrieves the value of the username."""
        return self.__username

    def __set_username(self, text):
        """Validates the username and sets its value."""
        self.__check_string(text, 'username')
        self.__username = text

    username = property(
        __get_username,
        __set_username,
        None,
        'Sets value of username.'
    )

    def __set_password(self, text):
        """Validates the password and sets its value."""
        self.__check_string(text, 'password')
        self.__password = text

    password = property(fset=__set_password, doc='Sets value of password.')

    def try_connect(self, callback=lambda status: None):
        """Attempt to connect to the pre-configured server address."""
        threading.Thread(target=self.__connect, args=(callback,)).start()

    def __connect(self, callback):
        """Connect to the server in an asynchronous fashion."""
        try:
            self.__server = smtplib.SMTP(self.HOST, self.PORT, None, 1)
        except (smtplib.SMTPException, socket.gaierror, socket.timeout):
            self.__cancel_connection()
        else:
            self.__is_connected = True
        callback(self.__is_connected)

    def send(self, destination, subject, message):
        """Try to send an e-mail with the provided information."""
        if self.__server is None:
            raise RuntimeError('cannot send without a valid connection')
        packet = email.mime.text.MIMEText(message)
        packet['From'] = self.__username
        packet['To'] = destination
        packet['Subject'] = subject
        self.__server.starttls()
        self.__server.login(self.__username, self.__password)
        self.__server.send_message(packet)
        self.__finish()

    def __cancel_connection(self):
        """Reset the is_connected and server attributes to default values."""
        self.__is_connected = False
        self.__server = None

    def validate_credentials(self):
        """Verify if the saved credentials are correct or not."""
        if self.__server is None:
            raise RuntimeError('cannot validate without a working connection')
        try:
            self.__server.starttls()
            self.__server.login(self.__username, self.__password)
        except smtplib.SMTPException:
            self.__is_logged_in = False
        else:
            self.__is_logged_in = True
        finally:
            self.__finish()
        return self.__is_logged_in

    def __finish(self):
        """Finish the conversation taking place with the server."""
        self.__server.close()
        self.__cancel_connection()


class Dialog(Toplevel):

    """Generic widget that should be used as a base class."""

    X_OFFSET = 50
    Y_OFFSET = 50

    def __init__(self, parent, title=None, icon_handle=None):
        """Initialize a Dialog window that takes focus away from the parent."""
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.withdraw()
        if icon_handle is not None:
            self.iconbitmap(icon_handle)
        if parent.winfo_viewable():
            self.transient(parent)
        if title:
            self.title(title)
        self.parent = parent
        self.result = None
        body = Frame(self)
        self.initial_focus = self.body(body)
        body.grid(sticky=NSEW, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.okay_button = self.cancel_button = None
        self.button_box()
        if not self.initial_focus:
            self.initial_focus = self
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.cancel)
        parent = self.parent
        if parent is not None:
            self.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(
                parent.winfo_rootx() + self.X_OFFSET,
                parent.winfo_rooty() + self.Y_OFFSET
            ))
        self.deiconify()
        self.initial_focus.focus_set()
        try:
            self.wait_visibility()
        except tkinter.TclError:
            pass
        else:
            self.grab_set()
            self.wait_window(self)

    def destroy(self):
        """Destruct the Dialog window."""
        self.initial_focus = None
        super().destroy()

    def body(self, master):
        """Create the body of this Dialog window."""
        pass

    def button_box(self):
        """Create the standard buttons and Dialog bindings."""
        box = Frame(self)
        self.okay_button = Button(
            box,
            text='Okay',
            width=10,
            command=self.okay,
            default=ACTIVE
        )
        self.okay_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.cancel_button = Button(
            box,
            text='Cancel',
            width=10,
            command=self.cancel
        )
        self.cancel_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bind('<Return>', self.okay)
        self.bind('<Escape>', self.cancel)
        box.grid()

    @event_handler
    def okay(self):
        """Validate and apply the changes made by this Dialog."""
        if self.validate():
            self.withdraw()
            self.update_idletasks()
            try:
                self.apply()
            finally:
                self.cancel()
        else:
            self.initial_focus.focus_set()

    @event_handler
    def cancel(self):
        """Close the Dialog window and return to its parent."""
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.parent.focus_set()
        self.destroy()

    def validate(self):
        """Verify that the Dialog is in a valid state."""
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def apply():
        """Make any changes the Dialog wishes to accomplish."""
        pass


class LoginWindow(Dialog):

    """Widget to allow easy process for supplying credentials."""

    TITLE = 'E-mail Login'
    WIDTH = 45
    MASK = '*'

    def __init__(self, parent, icon_handle, data_handler):
        """Initialize the dialog with the necessary information."""
        self.__data_handler = data_handler
        super().__init__(parent, self.TITLE, icon_handle)
        self.__username_label = self.__password_label = self.__username = \
            self.__password = None

    def body(self, master):
        """Create all the different widgets needed for the body."""
        self.__username_label = Label(master, text='Gmail Address:')
        self.__password_label = Label(master, text='Password:')
        self.__username = Entry(master, width=self.WIDTH)
        self.__password = Entry(master, width=self.WIDTH, show=self.MASK)
        self.__username_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)
        self.__username.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=EW)
        self.__password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)
        self.__password.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=EW)
        self.bind('<Key>', self.refresh)
        return self.__username

    def button_box(self):
        """Create the button box and change okay button's options."""
        super().button_box()
        self.okay_button.configure(state=DISABLED, text='Login')

    @event_handler
    def refresh(self):
        """Perform a soft validation for the username and password."""
        username = self.__username.get()
        password = self.__password.get()
        valid = re.search(r'\A(\w|\.)+@gmail\.com\Z', username) is not None \
            and len(password) > 3
        self.okay_button['state'] = ACTIVE if valid else DISABLED

    def validate(self):
        """Attempt to validate username and password with the server."""
        self.__data_handler.username = self.__username.get()
        self.__data_handler.password = self.__password.get()
        valid = self.__data_handler.validate_credentials()
        if valid:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(
                'Login Success',
                'The credentials were accepted.\n'
                'You are now logged in!',
                master=self
            )
        else:
            self.__password.delete(0, END)
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror(
                'Login Error',
                'This username/password combination was not accepted.\n'
                'Please try again.',
                master=self
            )
        return valid


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SMTPClient.main()
```

Comment: I have to say... I'm genuinely impressed with your effort! WOW. I doubt I would be able to implement your complexified code. I have a question: What do you think about the original code? Is it poorly written/decent? Any suggestions? I'm just half a year into hard core python learning anyways. Waiting for your answer!

Comment: Your code could use some documentation (strings), and you should try eliminating PEP8 violations. See the following reports for more information: [data_handler.py](http://pep8online.com/s/MewjCBlC), [help_gui.py](http://pep8online.com/s/kfrnLGaJ), [login_gui.py](http://pep8online.com/s/XWyXL8Le), [root_gui.py](http://pep8online.com/s/FYlAUUVn), [settings_gui.py](http://pep8online.com/s/tCkRol7O) Your `DataHandler` class does not look all that Pythonic to me. If you want to use it the way you are trying, you should use `classmethod` instead of `staticmethod`. Could you run my code fine?

Comment: I know about PEP 8, I mostly do refactoring after I acheive my desired functionality and I also felt really guilty about the staticmethods, Your code is running probably way smoother than mine. I will work on the comments and documentation ( it was a big dilema for me if I should/should not use comments )

Comment: One problem that you would probably experience with just about any GUI library you might come across is that they are usually not thread-safe. `tkinter` is no different in this regard. That is why my code uses `safetkinter`, a wrapper around tkinter's classes that automatically routes all calls through a delegate system that ensures the code executes on a single thread. GUI methods that you write yourself and are intended to run in a separate thread must be decorated with `@threadbox.MetaBox.thread` to work properly. Calls to non-decorated methods automatically get sent to the delegate system.

Comment: Umm, could you dumb it down for me? I'm only 6 months into python you see :)

Comment: Well, you are knowledgeable enough to know about GUI programming, SMTP communications, and running threads. This is probably my 10th year working with Python and 14th year programming, but your experience and drive to develop your own applications is fairly impressive. It would be nice to find more people like you that enjoy building programs as much as you have demonstrated. You are familiar enough with `tkinter` to use it on your own. If you would like to see the `safetkinter` module and related files, go to line 496 of the program on PasteBin, and change `delete=True` to be `delete=False`.

Comment: I'm 17 yo now and looking forward to a professional career, thanks for your positive feedback!  I will probably learn some other programming languages when I'll be satisfied with my python skills.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more ideas for preloading a window before displaying anything to the user. Specifically, do not execute the `mainloop` of the application until loading is complete. The main disadvantage is that the program might a take a while to appear. Both the `main` function and the `main` method finish setting up the frame before the root window is ever displayed. The code at the bottom of the example randomly picks an implementation to run, but both version accomplish the same thing for the user.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import contextlib
import random
import time
import tkinter


def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    frame = Application(root)
    frame.setup_frame('Hello, world!', ' ' * 50)
    frame.grid()
    root.mainloop()


class Application(tkinter.Frame):

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        with cls.setup_root('Tkinter Program') as root:
            root.resizable(False, False)
            frame = cls(root)
            frame.setup_frame('Hello, world!', ' ' * 50)
            frame.grid()

    @staticmethod
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def setup_root(title):
        tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        root.title(title)
        yield root
        root.after_idle(root.deiconify)
        root.mainloop()

    def setup_frame(self, *args):
        self.after_idle(self.__setup, *args)

    def __setup(self, *args):
        time.sleep(5)   # simulate taking a long time
        self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text='{1}{0}{1}'.format(*args))
        self.label.grid()
        self.button = tkinter.Button(
            self,
            text='Raise a KeyboardInterrupt exception.',
            command=lambda: self.throw(KeyboardInterrupt)
        )
        self.button.grid()

    @staticmethod
    def throw(kind):
        raise kind()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.choice((main, Application.main))()
```