# Tkinter does not update while withdrawn

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have a program that will show an image on screen when a hotkey is pressed on my keyboard. Depending on which key was pressed a different image will be shown.
After 3 seconds of no input my root Tk gets `withdraw()`n so there is nothing on screen.

Now, whenever I want to show an image I call this function:

```
    def drawOverlay(self, index):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.overlayWidget, image=self.overlayImages[index])
        self.deiconify()
```

The problem is that I see the old image for a few milliseconds before it is replaced.

I tried to find out why there is the delay eventhough I `deiconify()` only after i switched the image and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39212770/8242711) which suggested to call `deiconify()` using the root's `after()`. I tried that and when it still didn't work I played around with the call and found out that calling

```
self.after(1000, self.deiconify())
```

causes the old image to appear for exactly 1 second after which it is replaced with the new one.

This leads me to believe that the `Tk` or the `Canvas` is unable to update while it is `withdraw()`n. Is there any way around this? I'd rather have a short delay before the image is displayed than the old image flashing on the screen for a few frames but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

**Edit**: So I'm an idiot for actually calling `deiconify` instead of just passing it to `after` because of the parantheses.
That does fix the old image appearing for the duration but does not fix the flashing.

**Edit2**: I managed to reproduce this problem with the following code.

Pressing any key on the keyboard will make a green rectagle appear. Waiting for it to vanish and then pressing another key will make a red rectangle appear.

Only sometimes can you see the flashes happening so try for a couple times. I did not manage to reproduce when `-transparentcolor` isnt set but I can't tell if this is due to the option being the problem or due to the reduced rendering times making the problem almost imperceptable. It is also a bit easier to see then `overrideredirect` is set.

**Edit3**: I have worked the code down further by using actual images. Even without the keypress or additional event callbacks this code produces a black flash before displaing the image. `-transparentcolor` and `overrideredirect(True)` seem to be vital to reproducing this. Manually calling `update()` before reduces the frequency of this ocurring but still causes flashing consistently on larger images. This points to rendering time being one of the factors.

[overlay.png](https://sharedat.allions.net/?otUUblMX.png)

[overlayRaw.png](https://sharedat.allions.net/?CPFNLyt3.png)

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

TRANSCOLOR = "blue"
IMAGE_SMALL = "overlay.png"
IMAGE_LARGE = "overlayRaw.png"

class Overlay(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.rawImage = Image.open(IMAGE_SMALL)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.rawImage)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width = self.rawImage.size[0], height = self.rawImage.size[1])
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', TRANSCOLOR) # If disabled stops the flashes from ocurring even on large images. 
        self.overrideredirect(True)     # If disabled the Windows animation for opening windows plays. Stops the flashing from ocurring

        self.withdraw()

        self.overlayWidget = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.image, anchor = "nw")

        self.deiconify()              # Flashes Clearly Everytime

##        self.update_idletasks()
##        self.deiconify()              # Only Flashes Sometimes. Always flashes on large images

##        self.update()
##        self.deiconify()              # Only Flashes Sometimes. Always flashes on large images

##        self.after(0, self.deiconify) # Flashes Clearly everytime

##        self.after(200, self.deiconify) # Only Flashes Sometimes. Always flashes on large images

##        self.update()
##        self.after(200, self.deiconify) # Flashes Clearly Everytime

o = Overlay()
o.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.after(1000, self.deiconify())` does not do what you think it does. It calls `deiconify` immediately, then sleeps for one second.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and let us know what platform you are running on.

Comment: @BryanOakley I just noticed myself. That does not fix the entire problem unfortunately. I added the source code for my Tk Class. I'm working on Windows 8.1

Comment: Please don't provide all of that code. Create a [mcve]. What you posted has too much irrelevant code.

Comment: @BryanOakley updated again

Comment: Please read what a [mcve] is. Your code isn't complete, nor is it minimum. For example, is `resizable` really part of the problem?

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry for being ignorant. I added a working example. It does depend on `pillow` and `keyboard` though

Comment: what happens if you change `after(0, ...)` to `after(100, ...)`? Also, what happens if  you an explicit call to `self.update()` _before_ calling  `self.deiconify`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much that could cause a flicker. My recommendation would be to add an explicit call to `self.update` before the call to `deiconify` happens. That should instruct tkinter to redraw everything on the canvas. However, that won't help if tkinter on your platform defers drawing until the window is mapped.

Try replacing this:

```
self.after(0,self.deiconify)
self.after(2000, self.hideOverlay)
```

with this:

```
self.update()
self.deiconify()
```

Comment: I added a more reliable example. if you can't reproduce this problem with the larger image then `Windows 8.1` seems to be the problem as my laptop gets the same results as my PC